# How to create a new request

Tags: php, laravel

I have a method that accepts a request

```php
public function createUser(Request $request)
{
    ...
}
```

I want to call it from another method

```php
public function someMethod(){
    $array = [...];

    return $this->createUser($array); <----
}
```

and how can I pass a new request to it with the array I need?

Comment: How about instead of trying to call a controller method, you move the logic to create a user to a service class and then use the service class in your `createUser` and `someMethod` methods?

Comment: @bassxzero Can you show me an example of this approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about instead of trying to call a controller method, you move the logic to create a user to a service class and then use the service class in your createUser and someMethod methods?

UserService.php

```
class UserService
{

    public function __construct() { }

    public function createUser(array $userData)
    {
        // TODO use $userData to create a user here

        return $newUser;
    }
}
```

SomeController.php

```
public function createUser(Request $request)
{
    $this->userService->createUser($request->all());
}


public function someMethod(){
    $array = [...];

    return $this->userService->createUser($array);
}
```