# How to pass request object in laravel from one file to another file?

Tags: php, laravel, constructor, apiato

I have 3 files called `RequestCriteria,GetAllDataTask,GetAllDataAction` .

`RequestCriteria.php`

```
public function __construct(Request $request)
    {
        
        $this->request = $request;
    }
```

`GetAllDataTask.php`

```
public function run( $data)
    {
$this->repository->pushCriteria(new RequestCriteria($data));
}
```

`GetAllDataAction.php`

```
public function run(Request $request){
   $data=$request->all();
$result=Apiato::call("Books@GetAllDataTask",[$data]);
}
```

when i am passing $data in GetAllDataTask.php  while calling the RequestCriteria it's throwing an error called `The $data must be an Request object \\Illuminate\Http\\Request`
,How to fix this issue please help me

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a new request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70015120/how-to-create-a-new-request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Action file it's already  `$request` is an Request class object so you have to update in `RequestCriteria.php`.

```
public function __construct($newObj)
    {
        
        $this->request = $newObj;
    }
```

i hope this will work...

Comment: ,Thanks it helps me alot...)